# How to configure Cucumber feature file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, gherkin, feature-file

I have a feature file as below:

```
Feature: Log in to the application

@OnlyOneTime
  Scenario: Login to application as valid user
    When User enter the valid credentials
    And Click on Login
    Then Home Page should be displayed

  Scenario: Login to application as Invalid user
    When User enter the inValid credentials
    And Click on Login
    Then Error Message Should be displayed
```

But the problem is it is being shown as plain file not at all with the gherkin colors, also I can't see ***find step*** option when I right click on a step.

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to see colors in feature file as they are supposed to for gherkin keywords.

Comment: You need to install editor for gherkin language in your eclipse. Go to help->marketplace and type "gherkin" in searchbar. After install you may need to restart eclipse.

Comment: @MateuszMarchel : I've already installed Cucumber Eclipse Plugin for eclipse

Comment: But still as I can see from screenshot your files are not opened with it, so you probably have something messed up with settings. Check general->editors->file associations in window->settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer :

> When everything is installed right, and if feature file does not display the gherkin colors, We need to first create a sample `cucumber.feature` file in the same path.
>
> Once this is created if it is auto-populated with sample gherkin code, then other feature file will also work or we can simply paste content of our feature file into `cucumber.feature` and then rename it.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a solution to this. Can't find anything on the web. So I keep looking on eclipse editor and found this.

1. Window -> Preferences
2. On the left side Preferences window click General -> Editors -> File Associations
3. on the right side click Add... Enter *.feature on the textbox then click OK
4. Select the newly added *.feature on the list
5. Under Associated editors click Add... then choose the Editor with the green cucumber icon. click okay
6. Apply and Close

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the following steps

-Right click on . feature file -> Open With -> Cucumber Editor